# How to retrieve different type of data in django?

Tags: django, django-views

I created an attendance management system and I want to retrieve the different types of date from the table. Like,

In my attendance table, there are different date but some date is repeated ex - for every date, there are number of users has attendance

```
staff table.                attendance table

id = 1                      id = 1
name = john                 staff_id = 1
                            date = 31.08.2021
id = 2                      attendance = present
name = harry 
                            id = 2
                            staff_id = 2
                            date = 31.08.2021
                            attendance = absent

                            id = 3
                            staff_id = 1
                            date = 01.09.2021
                            attendance = present

                            id = 4
                            staff_id = 2
                            date = 01.09.2021
                            attendance = present
```

from the above table data I wanted to retrieve the only date without repetition

so when we write code the answer will be

```
31.08.2021
01.09.2021
```

this is my template file

```
{% for attendances in attendance %}
    <th>{{ attendances.date }}</th>
    // here i want to retrive 31.08.2021 and 01.09.2021
{% endfor %}
```

This is my views file

```
def index(request):
    staffs = staff.objects.all()
    attendances = attendance.objects.all()
    date = datetime.date.today()

    return render(request, "salary/index.html", {'staff': staffs, 'attendance': attendances, 'date': date})
```

Comment: Why not prepare it yourself in the view and pass it in context?

Comment: how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from database directly (if you're using postgres), or prepare it yourself from `attendances`. Just do what's best for you.

```
def index(request):
    staffs = staff.objects.all()
    attendances = attendance.objects.all()
    date = datetime.date.today()
    
    
    # unique_dates = list(attendance.objects.all().order_by().values('date').distinct())
    # OR
    # unique_dates = list({a.date for a in atteendances})
    

    return render(request, "salary/index.html", {'staff': staffs, 'attendance': attendances, 'date': date, 'unique_dates': unique_dates})
```